# Angular compiler-cli error: Namespace 'ts' has no exported member 'ResolutionMode'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-compiler, angular-compiler-cli

I am developing a web application with Angular 16 in Webstorm.  The web application is currently pre-release and only has a small portion of minimum functionality completed.  I was editing with `ng serve` running testing changes as I made them when the compiler stopped compiling the app emitting the following error:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/program_driver/src/ts_create_program_driver.d.ts:37:247 - error TS2694: Namespace 'ts' has no exported member 'ResolutionMode'.

37     resolveTypeReferenceDirectives: ((typeReferenceDirectiveNames: string[] | readonly ts.FileReference[], containingFile: string, redirectedReference: ts.ResolvedProjectReference | undefined, options: ts.CompilerOptions, contain
ingFileMode?: ts.ResolutionMode) => (ts.ResolvedTypeReferenceDirective | undefined)[]) | undefined;
```

I have tried:

- removing all of my changes related to what I was working on (dismissing a modal dialog) including the service calls to my API
- updated the installed version of TypeScript,
- updated all Angular packages to ensure that they are all of the same version with one another.
- deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again just to be sure.
- cloned the repo to a new machine and attempted to build it there all with the same result ensuring this was not some weird environment fluke.

[Github repo exhibiting the problem.](https://github.com/CodeWarrior-Hawaii/TaxiCentralAdmin)

Has anyone ever had an instance where Angular just straight up does not recognize a base TypeScript member?  I have navigated to typescript.d.ts and ResolutionMode is in fact noted in there.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out updating typescript was what fixed it.  I don't know what I did before, when I THOUGHT I was updating typescript, nor why it took weeks for compiler-cli to decide to error out.

It appears that I WAS running Typescript 4.9.4.  Now, [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=15.0-16.0) SAYS that Typescript versions above 4.9.3 are required, but this appears to be not entirely correct.  Regardless, updating Typescript fixed the problem.

Comment: To what version did you update typescript? I running into the same issue, but a fresh install does not seem to work just like you mentioned in your question. Are you using 4.9.4 still? How did you update it finally?

Comment: @MZeinstra Version 5.2.2 which was the latest stable version at the time.  I did it through NPM as it was noted in the package.json.  I also ensured that my IDE, in this case Webstorm, was pointed at the same version because it did seem to have some problem that I can't recall the exact nature of until it was using the same version.